# Getting bad request while passing LocalDateFilter spring rest controller

Tags: java, spring, postman, jhipster, spring-restcontroller

```
/api/test?page=-1&size=50&nextDateOfScreening.greaterThan=2020-04-03&sort=id,asc
```

this is my passing url and in controller am receiving it as,

```
@GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ExampleDTO>> getAllTIBenScrDetails(ExampleCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable) {
        Page<ExampleDTO> page = tIBenScrDetailsQueryService.findByCriteria(criteria, pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
```

and  **ExampleCriteria** class as,

```
public class ExampleCriteria implements Serializable, Criteria {
    private LocalDateFilter nextDateOfScreening; //jhipster LocalDateFilter
}
```

and Iam getting bad request for the date filter as,

```
Field error in object 'ExampleCriteria' on field 'nextDateOfScreening.greaterThan': rejected value [2020-04-03]; codes [typeMismatch.ExampleCriteria.nextDateOfScreening.greaterThan,typeMismatch.nextDateOfScreening.greaterThan,typeMismatch.greaterThan,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [ExampleCriteria.nextDateOfScreening.greaterThan,nextDateOfScreening.greaterThan]; arguments []; default message [nextDateOfScreening.greaterThan]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'nextDateOfScreening.greaterThan'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDate] for value '2020-04-03'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2020-04-03]]
```

For *greaterThanEquals* and *lessThanEquals* bad request error is not getting but for *greaterThan* and *lessThan* error is there. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: more details ? logs ?

Comment: @CodeScale complete error log is added

Comment: So for exactly the same request `nextDateOfScreening.greaterThanEquals` is working ?

Comment: I'll try to reproduce myself. I come back to you later ;-)

Comment: no bad request is getting for ```nextDateOfScreening.greaterThanEquals```

Comment: Where does interface `Criteria` comes from?

Comment: from client side, angularJs, see the url above

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `greaterThanEquals` doesn't exist in `LocalDateFilter`. It is actually `greaterOrEqualThan` so
`nextDateOfScreening.greaterOrEqualThan`.

It is the reason it "works" because spring doesn't find the `LocalDateFilter` setter and so create an "empty" `LocalDateFilter`.

For `lessThan` the setter is found but conversion of `String` to `LocalDate` is not configured. And to solve that you have to declare a custom converter ->

```java
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@Component
public class LocalDateConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate convert(final String s) {
        return LocalDate.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Am getting a bad request, so that it is not getting inside the method. So when I can do this conversion?

Comment: Same same error? As I said you just have to register the converter with @Component... if the bean is scanned it should work

Comment: I reproduced myself

Comment: Did you add the converter ?

Comment: Thanks lot, it's working..I added the wrong Converter, that's why it's not worked

Comment: Hi, I have one more doubt. When I am passing other types like integer, boolean as request params, it will be treated as string. But in code am  using BooleanFilter, IntegerFilter etc. So am getting bad request. How can I convert String to this correponding filter types? (jhipster)

Comment: Could you open new issue with all details please?